# django image upload rest framework and test client

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to upload a picture with rest framework and to test it with the django test client. It almost works, however when I save the file I have this on the top of my file:

```
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="plop.png"
```

If I delete those lines, I can perfectly read my picture, but I don't know how to rid of them.

models.py

```
class GenericUser(User):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

views.py

```
class AvatarView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
    def post(self, request):
        up_file = request.data['file']
        user = get_object_or_404(GenericUser, pk=request.user.id)
        user.avatar.save(up_file.name, up_file)
        user.save()
        return Response(status=204)
```

tests.py

```
cl = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="Token {}".format(token))
with open(MY_FILE, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
res = cl.post('/avatar', {"plop.png" : data}, HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION="attachment; filename=plop.png;")
```

any hints, how I could make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked as I expected:
views.py

```
class AvatarView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    def post(self, request):
        up_file = request.data["file"]
        user = get_object_or_404(GenericUser, pk=request.user.id)
        user.avatar.save(up_file.name, up_file)
        user.save()
        return Response(status=204)
```

test.py

```
cl = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="Token {}".format(token))
with open(MY_FILE, 'rb') as f:
    res = cl.post('/avatar', {"file" : f})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
res = cl.post('/avatar?filename=plop.png', {"plop.png" : data})
```

Or more or less from the Django docs:

```
with open(MY_FILE, 'rb') as f:
    cl.post('/avatar', {"filename" : f})
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out, both solution failed. It seems that the django test client really need the HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION="attachment; filename=plop.png;" to format a request that FileUploadParser understands I'll try to figure out what's wrong using wireshark I guess

Comment: :( Did you try with the MultiPartParser? The text you are removing looks like the separator for multi-part MIME files. Also did you try the suggestion from DRF docs where the filename is part of the URL: url(r'^upload/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', FileUploadView.as_view())

Comment: Same fort the filename as part of the URL. I'm trying the MultiPartParser as we speak